# Is there a decent Vim regexp OR command? What is the best way to find mismatched if else's?

Tags: regex, vim

I have some mismatching if and fi statements in a script.  I would like to strip out everything but the if's else's and fi's.  Just so I can see the structure.  Why am working so HARD with such a powerful editor?  I need a **BIGFATOR** operator for regexp or some epiphany that has eluded me... I don't care for pontification on regular expressions just something practical working in VIM7.2.

> :g/[ ^\t]if [/print

will print out the ifs

> :g/[ ^\t]fi/print

will printout the fi

What I want to do is or the conditions

:g/[ ^\t]fi **BIGFATOROPERATOR** [ ^\t]fi/print

I have had success doing the following... but I feel I am working TOO HARD!

> :call TripMatch('[ ^\t]*if [', 'else', 'fi[ \t$]')
>
> function! TripMatch(str1, str2, str3)
>
> let var1 = a:str1
>
> let var2 = a:str2
>
> let var3 = a:str3
>
> let max = line("$")
>
> let n = 1
>
> for n in range (1, max)
>
> let currentline = getline(n)
>
> ```
> if currentline =~? var1
>
>    echo n "1:" currentline
>
> else
>
>    if currentline =~? var2
>
>       echo n "2:" currentline
>
>    else
>
>       if currentline =~? var3
>
>          echo n "3:" currentline
>
>       else
>
>          let foo = "do nothing"
>
>       endif
>
>    endif
>
> endif
> ```
>
> endfor
>
> endfunction

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
:g/[ ^\t]if\|[ ^\t]fi/print
```

**BIGFATOROPERATOR** is `\|`.  It's called the [alternation operator](http://devmanual.gentoo.org/tools-reference/sed/index.html).  In PCRE, it's plain `|`.  It's escaped in Vim/ex because `|` is used elsewhere for general commands (or something -- FIXME).

Comment: Are you infact escaping the | character in that?

Comment: In my defense there is an awful lot of noise searching for these things... and a I did learn a lot in the process.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to remove all other lines aside from those with if, else or fi you can use this

```
%v/\(if\|else\|fi\)/d
```

'v' is the opposite of 'g' and will remove any lines that don't match the regexp.

To add to what strager said,  the pipe character '|' is escaped in Vim, I imagine because Vim assumes you'll be looking for literal characters more often than you will have need of extensive RegExps.

You can make Vim use less escaped RegExps by setting the 'magic' level to 'very' when in ex mode:

> Use of "\v" means that in the pattern
>   after it all ASCII characters except
>   '0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have
>   a special meaning.  "very magic"

*See :he /magic for more information*

It is not recommended that you set the default magic level to 'very' in your vimrc though (as the help file notes).

Comment: alternation operator yet again... where did I miss this in my education?

Comment: The unescaped pipe character is used to string Ex commands together. For example
  :bufdo retab | update
will execute :retab and :update on every buffer.

Answer (score 10):

```
:h /\|
```

If you missed \|, you probably have missed many other [pattern](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/help?tag=pattern) "tokens".