# Regular expression for non negatives and format of ##.##

Tags: regex

I have a requirement for non negatives that should be greater than 0 (zero), allow any povitive number and allow this ##.## format also. I tried with

```
^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

This should allow bellow formats..

```
00.10
0.1
00.1
122222
```

and it should be prohibit

```
0,
00.00,
000000,
10.1111
```

It's supporting all my requirements, but it allows all zeros too. So it should be prohibited to enter only digits which are zero, including a single zero in a text box.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am using    ^\d+(.\d{1,2})?$   format.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/regexp/thread/17089c0f-f9cb-437a-9667-ba8329681624

Comment: it should allow ** 00.01,0.1,00.1,00.10,11122222256  **--- but restrict single  0 zero.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker too, so I have a lot of errors in my texts, too, but let me recommend an spelling-plug-in for your browser. It will at least catch 'tahn' instead of 'than' and 'negitive' and so on.

Comment: The problem isn't well suited for a regex. Can't you have a combined check - one for the format, and a second for the value, the second without regex? That's how I would do it in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for your example in VI editor:

```
^[1-9]\d*\.\?\d\{1,2}$\|^0\+\.\d*[1-9]\d*$
```

If you are not trying in VI, then you might have to remove the escaping characters (`\`)

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

<strike>^[1-9]\d?(?:.\d\d?)?$</strike>

Updated

It's a little bit clearer with your examples.

In Perl, I'd do a first test with the regex 
and if it matches, then compare the value with 0

```
if ($value =~ /^\d+(,:\.\d\d?)?$/ && $value != 0) {
    print "OK\n";
} else {
    print "Wrong value\n";
}
```

Comment: Here we need to use ^ symbol.

Comment: @rajesh p: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @M42:I am looking for Client side solution in Asp.net web pages.

Comment: @rajesh p: Sorry, I don't know ASP but I think the code above could be adapted without difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `\d+` with `[1-9]\d*`. It worked in my vi.

Comment: I tried like this ^[1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$ but it wont allowing 00.01 value. Any other suggestion? it should allow 00.01,0.1,00.1,00.10,11122222256--- but restrict single 0 zero.

Comment: [1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$ This is the answer. Thanks Rahul.

Comment: But it still allowing 00.111111 can we avoid?

Comment: Try this: ^[1-9]\d*\.\d{2,2}\|0*\.\d*[1-9]$ This is basically two different regexp joined using an alternation operator - \| (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680022/is-there-a-decent-vim-regexp-or-command-what-is-the-best-way-to-find-mismatched)

Comment: @rajesh p: Didn't the pattern in my last comment work? if its not working, please edit your question and some test numbers that can i try out.

Comment: Added some example formats in my question please go through that.