# Vim regex to substitute/escape pipe characters

Tags: regex, vim

Let's suppose I have a line:

```
a|b|c
```

I'd like to run a regex to convert it to:

```
a\|b\|c
```

In most regex engines I'm familiar with, something like `s%\|%\\|%g` should work. If I try this in Vim, I get:

```
\|a\||\|b\||\|c
```

---

As it turns out, I discovered the answer while typing up this question. I'll submit it with my solution, anyway, as I was a bit surprised a search didn't turn up any duplicates.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

vim has its own regex syntax. There is a comparison with PCRE in vim help doc (see `:help perl-patterns`).

except for that, vim has no magic/magic/very magic mode. `:h magic` to check the table.

by default, vim has `magic` mode. if you want to make the `:s` command in your question work, just active the `very magic`:

```
:s/\v\|/\\|/g
```

Answer (score 10):

Vim does the opposite of PCRE in this regard: `|` is a literal pipe character, with [`\|` serving as the alternation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680022/is-there-a-decent-vim-regexp-or-command-what-is-the-best-way-to-find-mismatched). I couldn't find an appropriate escape sequence because the pipe character does not need to be escaped.

The following command works for the line in my example:

```
:. s%|%\\|%g
```

Comment: you'll be interested to read about `magic`, `nomagic` and _very magic_ pattern modes

Answer (score 3):

If you use `very-magic` (use `\v`) you'll have the Perl/pcre behaviour on most special characters (excl. the vim specifics):

```
:s#\v\|#\\|#g
```