# Regexp: How to match one of two exactly specified 4 digit numbers

Tags: regex, vim

I am looking at a large file in vim that has a whole lot of numbers in it. I am looking for a specific record that has the number 1119 in one field, and I know 2 records later there is a number 1196 in the same field.

I would like to search for either but have both highlighted,

I have tried:

```
[1119|1196] which matches any of these single digits like 1.
{1119|1196} doesn't find anything (I am not sure what it looks for).
{1119,1196}
```

doesn't find anything either. I am surprised at this, as I think it should look for either 1119 or 1196, and those numbers definitly exist lots of times in the file.

I have also tried putting /g for global at the end, but that did not help either.

I also tried

```
(1119|1196), and that did not work either.
```

I also tried

```
((1119)|(1196)) and that did not work either.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to escape special characters: `\(1119\|1196\)`. See [VimRegex.com](http://vimregex.com/). However, usually, you do not have to group the whole pattern, I'd remove the round brackets altogether.

Comment: But they are part of the regexp, not part of the thing I am searching for.

Comment: I am only searching for those 4 digit numbers. The | was supposed to be part of the regexp that means "searching for either the thing on the left of the | or the thing on the right of the |"

Comment: Hey wow, you guys are right! Escaping the | worked! I did not find that intuitive at all, as I don't normally escape part of the regexp syntax only the actual things I am searching for. You should make an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @Kurt I don't follow you. `|` in regex is a logical OR operator. As @stribizhev says, it needs escaping in `vim`

Comment: Now I understand, I really did not expect that actual regexp operators should need to be escaped in vim. What happens if I was searching for a |? A double escape? VIM is strange.

Comment: @Kurt: To just search for a pipe, I think you can use an unescaped `|`, or `[|]`. Or, check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882255/vim-regex-to-substitute-escape-pipe-characters) for "very magic" Vim mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [VimRegex.com](http://vimregex.com/#pattern):

> **4.6 Alternations**
>   Using `\|` you can combine several expressions into one which matches any of its components. The first one matched will be used.
>
> `\(Date:\|Subject:\|From:\)\(\s.*\)`

So, you need to escape special characters:

```
\(1119\|1196\)
```

Since the grouping here is applied to the whole pattern that can be referenced with `\0` (*\0 -> the whole matched pattern*), you can safely use

```
1119\|1196
```

to search for the two numbers.

However, if you need to find the two numbers as whole words, use `\<`/`\>` word boundaries (then, grouping is fine):

```
\<\(1119\|1196\)\>
```